# Sufficient Condition for stable Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be some Banach space, $\mathcal{L}(X)$ be the space of bounded linear operators $T:X\to X$ with $\mathrm{dom}(T)=X$.

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and $(T_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{L}(X)$.

> We define stable convergence of $T_n$ to $T$ ($T_n\overset{s}{\to}T)$ by
>
> 1. $\forall x\in X:\ T_nx\to Tx$,
> 2. $\exists M>0,N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n>N: T_n^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and $\Vert T_n^{-1}\Vert \leq M$.

I am struggling now with following argument: Let $S\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and $z\in\rho(S)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:(S-z)^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(X)\}$, consider a sequence $S_n\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ with $S_nx\to S x\ \forall x\in X$. The proof I am trying to understand now uses

> Stability of $S_n-z$ can be written as $\Vert (S_n-z)x_n \Vert\geq M \Vert x_n\Vert$ for $x_n\in X, n\geq N$. (*)

I See that (*) is necessary for the stable convergence, but why is this condition sufficient for $S_n-z$ having an inverse in $\mathcal{L}(X)$?

For example: If I take $T:\mathcal{l}^2\to\mathcal{l}^2,\ (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,)\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$, I clearly have $\Vert Tx\Vert=\Vert x \Vert$ but $T$ is not surjective.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is $\rho(S)$ the spectrum of the operator?

Comment: Isn't there a typo then: it should write $z\in\rho(S)=\{z\in\Bbb{C}:(S-z\operatorname{Id})^{-1}\in\mathcal{L}(x)\}$

Comment: You wrote $T-z$ in your post

Comment: Oh I See! Thanks.

Comment: In your statement ($*$), what is $x_n$?

Comment: @GeorgeBrown I asked this myself too. I would say the author means arbitrary $x\in X$. The reason she already choses an arbitrary sequence $x_n$ is because of the following part of the proof (which is clear to me), where she shows (*) holds by contradiction. There she takes a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $(S_{n_k}-z)x_{n_k}\to 0$.

Comment: I'm confused: if $\|(S_n-z)x_n\|\ge M\|x_n\|$, then isn't $(S_n-z)$ an unbounded operator, so not in $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: @FShrike I don't think so, you can think of the right shift in the original post which is also bounded.

Comment: @GrafZahl The statement ($*$) reminds me of the following proposition: Let $X, Y$ be  Banach spaces and $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, then $T^{-1}:T(X)\to X$ is continuous iff there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\|Tx\|_Y\geq c\|x\|_X$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: To be bounded, there must exist an $M$ such that the inequality is $\le$, not $\ge$, no?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, but why can't $c\Vert x\Vert \leq \Vert Tx\Vert \leq C\Vert x\Vert$ hold for $c<C$? Again, there is an example in the post with $\Vert Tx\Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ which contains both kind of inequality.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown This is also a nice statement, in fact this kind of convergence seems to have some nice properties.

Comment: @GrafZahl What is the book you referred to？

Comment: @GeorgeBrown Chatelin's "Spectral Approximation of Linear Operators", Proposition 3.17., https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611970678 .

Comment: @GrafZahl At the bottom paragraph on p. 75, the author says "T is invertible iff $\text{Ker}\, T =\{0\}$", but in most textbooks,  "$\text{Ker}\, T=\{0\}$ means $T$ is injective. I think it is a problem of terminology.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown I thought about that too, but on the other hand, in my understanding $\mathrm{dom}(T^{-1})=\mathrm{range}(T)$. Now $T^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ implies $\mathrm{dom}(T^{-1})=X$ (the paragraph above), which in my opinion means $T$ should be surjective.

Comment: @GrafZahl At the first paragraph on p. 132, "assuming that $z\in \rho(T_n)$ for $n$ large enough." I think maybe the following arguments are under this special assumption? Also, the author writes $R_n(z)$ in the next section, which seems to confirm my guess.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown I am not sure about your interpretation here. The fist sentence you are referring to means in my opinion that if the $R_n(z)$ exist we can define a new sort of convergence. And stable convergence implies existence of these $R_n(z)$, so why should we make such a strong assumption? And shouldn't this be also mentioned in the table on page 137?

Comment: @GrafZahl Sorry, I am puzzled why $R_n(z)$ makes sense in the sentence just following eq. (3.7), (3.8) and in  Lemma 3.16 (ii)$\Rightarrow$(i).

Comment: @GeorgeBrown I See what you mean. My personal interest is Proposition 5.3, which uses eq. (5.3) on page 231. There, it also says that stable convergence implies $z\in \rho(T_n)$ for $n$ large enough, so I do not think it is an assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously not sufficient. Consider the operators $S_n$ in $\ell^2$ defined by
$$
x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto S_nx=(x_1,\dots,x_n,0,x_{n+1},\dots)
$$
Then $S_nx\to x$ for all $x$ and you have the lower bound (with $z=0$) but not invertibility for every $S_n$.

Most likely, the words "can be written as" should be read as "implies", not as "is equivalent to" or, as noted in the comments, the book uses some non-standard terminology that hasn't been thought through thoroughly enough not to lead to occasional contradictions.

Comment: Thanks for this really nice counterexample. It looks to me like the statement in the book is wrong. The author wants to prove $(S_n-z)\xrightarrow{s}(S-z)\Leftrightarrow (S_n-z)\xrightarrow{r}(S-z)$. Here $T_n\xrightarrow {r}T$ is called regular convergence, i.e. $T_nx \to T_x \ \forall x\in X$ and if $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $X$ such that $T_{n_k}x_{n_k}\to y\in X$ for some subsequence, then there is a sub-subsequence such that $x_{n_{k_l}}\to x\in X$ and $Tx=y$. And indeed, if we take $z=0$ it looks like your example is moreover an example for regular, but not stable convergence.